# How to test the color changes done on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, colors

I wanted to replace 10 specific colors to new colors as per requirement (eg: #ddd to #000. Different replacements like this). I just did find and replace in over 300 places in all css files.
Now, wanted to test in website that if all colors are correctly replaced. As it is over 300 places, its difficult to understand which color is used where.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: if you wan't to check if #ddd is still in the code use "grep" on the server or the search function of your editor

Comment: If you know the colors to check, you can search them with your code editor. For example VSCode or Sublime Text allows you to search terms in a folder. Also, you could use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to avoid changing 300 variables by hand if the value is the same.

Comment: just copy the files and move it into a testing location/space and test the changes there. Any decent developer team will also sue Git/GitHub for such purposes to keep track of changes made.

Comment: I would have an intermediary step because what if you change #ddd to #000 and then want to change #000 to #fff? It will also be difficult to keep track of changes once you've lost the information about what the original color was. I'd first change all occurences of #ddd to var(--col-ddd) or similar and set the variables accordingly. That way you can unravel things if some mistake is made.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to make sure that replaced colors are correct from the browser, without code access.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you want to change one specific color to another specific color in the code.
so there is option in VS Code to search specific string and change to other.

In addition, to prevent this - I recommend you to use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) (variables).

---> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: It is not VSC specific. A search and replace function exist in every text or code editor and can be opened in every program with `Ctrl + H`. While the rest is not wrong it does not answer the actual question.

Comment: No sorry, I mean I've already replaced and want to check in website if replaced correctly or not.

Comment: Why not just run it on live server?